# Vue 3 Composition API...how to replace getElementById

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I wrote the following in Vue 3 Composition API.

If you look on the "onMounted" I'm attaching an event listener to the window to keep the status box to the bottom of the screen. I'm using absolute position and bottom 0.

I'm wondering if I can make this more "Vue" by replacing the getElementById? I tried refs but it's not working.

Any suggestions or should I leave well enough alone?

Thanks

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <transition name="toast">
      <div id="slide" class="slide-modal" v-if="statuses.length">
        <div class="clear-notifications" @click='clearAllNotifications()'>Clear all notifications</div>
        <div v-for="status in statuses" :key="status.id" class="status-div">
          <div>{{ status.text }}</div>
          <div @click="closeStatus(status)"><span class="-x10-cross"></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, ref, computed, watch, onMounted } from "vue";
  import { useStore } from "../model/DataStore";
  export default defineComponent({ 
    setup() {
    const store = useStore();

    const statuses = ref([]);

    const statusMessage = computed(() => store.state.statusMessage);
    function  addStatus(newMessage) {

          statuses.value.push({
            id: statuses.value.length + 1,
            text: newMessage
          })
        }

      watch(statusMessage, (newValue: string, oldValue: string) => {
        addStatus(statusMessage.value);
      })

      onMounted(() => {
          window.addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {
                let vertical_position = 0;
                vertical_position = pageYOffset;

                if(document.getElementById("slide")){
                  document.getElementById('slide').style.bottom = -(vertical_position) + 'px';
                }
          });
      })

    return {
      store,
      statuses,
      addStatus
    };
  },
  methods: {
        clearAllNotifications() {
          this.statuses = []
        },

        closeStatus(elm: any) {
          const index = this.statuses.map((status) => status.id).indexOf(elm.id);
          this.statuses.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
  })
</script>
```

and here's the slide modal style:

```css
    .slide-modal {
        max-height: 200px;
        width: 500px;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        color: #505050;
        padding: 8px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 8px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is the code when you replace to ref?

Comment: if(document.getElementById("slide")){
                  document.getElementById('slide').style.bottom = -(vertical_position) + 'px';
                }

Comment: I want to not use the document.getElementById.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html) give a pretty simple example

```html
<template>
  <div ref="root">This is a root element</div>
</template>

<script>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

  export default {
    setup() {
      const root = ref(null)

      onMounted(() => {
        // the DOM element will be assigned to the ref after initial render
        console.log(root.value) // <div>This is a root element</div>
      })

      return {
        root
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

- use ref() when creating
- pass to template in return function
- use `ref="..."` in template
- and in `onMounted`, access via `ref.value`

so for your code it would be...

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <transition name="toast">
      <div ref="slideRef" class="slide-modal" v-if="statuses.length">
        <div class="clear-notifications" @click='clearAllNotifications()'>Clear all notifications</div>
        <div v-for="status in statuses" :key="status.id" class="status-div">
          <div>{{ status.text }}</div>
          <div @click="closeStatus(status)"><span class="-x10-cross"></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, ref, computed, watch, onMounted } from "vue";
  import { useStore } from "../model/DataStore";
  export default defineComponent({ 
    setup() {
    const store = useStore();

    const statuses = ref([]);
    const slideRef = ref();

    const statusMessage = computed(() => store.state.statusMessage);
    function  addStatus(newMessage) {
          statuses.value.push({
            id: statuses.value.length + 1,
            text: newMessage
          })
        }

      watch(statusMessage, (newValue: string, oldValue: string) => {
        addStatus(statusMessage.value);
      })

      onMounted(() => {
          window.addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {
                let vertical_position = 0;
                vertical_position = pageYOffset;

                if(slideRef.value){
                  slideRef.value.style.bottom = -(vertical_position) + 'px';
                }
          });
      })

    return {
      store,
      statuses,
      addStatus,
      slideRef 
    };
  },
  })
</script>
```